# How to redirect to default server index page using php ternary operator?

Tags: php

---

I had tried to check the server name protocol using php ternary operator ?

Here is example and code:

Example:https://9.218.145.189

example code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])?($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='ON'):($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='OFF');?>">Click here</a>
```

QUery:

1. If my HTTP/HTTPS is ON/OFF it should redirect me to the https://9.218.145.189 home page when i click href link(i.e 9.218.145.189) instead it is redirecting me to the https://9.212.145.189/outpt.php.

Error:

THe above code for  a href link is not taking me to the https link.

Comment: `$server['HTTPS'] = 'ON'` should be `$server['HTTPS'] == 'ON'`

Comment: Even if it works, you will have just `ON` href to the Anchor tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI:

`=` is assignment operator

`==` is comparision operator

Hence try the following code(modified):

```
<a href="<?php echo $SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])?($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']='ON'):($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']='OFF'); ?>">Click here</a>
```